# What can i do with this Aloe Arborescens?

Tags: cuttings, aloe

i have this plant but it's terribly heavy and unbalanced. I don't know much about aloe but i don't think it should look like this, especially because without a stick the plant just falls over.

So my question is, is it possile to cut the aloe in the pointed space and replant it?

[image: Bending Aloe Arborescens]

Maybe it has something to do with the small vase but i live in a small apartment and i cannot afford a huge vase spot.

Anyway, suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that *Aloe arborescens* is a tree-sized plant in the wild. The name "arborescens" means "tree-like" in Latin. When fully grown it is between 6 and 10 feet tall. In South Africa it was used as a hedge around enclosures for cattle. It's not a little indoor plant!

You could try cutting off the top of the plant (say two leaves above the arrow in your picture) and growing it as a cutting, but a better long term solution would be to get a different species of aloe which doesn't grow so tall. *Aloe vera* will grow to about 2 feet tall with a 3-foot flower spike. A popular small variety is *Aloe variegata*, but there are many others - see [here](https://wimastergardener.org/article/small-aloes-interesting-colorful-and-easy-succulents) for a selection of pictures.